# How to add table rows when button clicked: jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a template which contains two add buttons and two tables. When user clicks add button rows should append to the respective table. 
Example:

```
<div class="reports">
   <div class="panel">
    <table class="A">
     <thead>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
     </thead>
     <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
   <button class="add" type="button">Add</button>
  </div>
```

Am using same code for creating table and add button with different ids report.js is

```
$('.reports').on('click','.add',function(){
      //do something
});
```

I want rows to be appended to the respective table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have different ids at parent divs

```
$('.reports').on('click','.add',function(){
    $(this)  //button that was clicked
   .parent() //div around the button
     .siblings(".A")  //sibling element that has the table
       .find("table tbody")  //the table
         .append(tableRow);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [**append()**](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$('.reports').on('click','.add',function(){
      $(this).closest('.reports').find('table').append('<tr/>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The vanilla Js approach:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('add');
var table = document.getElementsByClassName('A');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  table.appendChild(tr);
});
```